# PHP code that subtracts from SQL when link is used

Tags: php, sql

Good Day

I have a link that does the following

```
<a href="/lbs_map.php" target="_blank" class="update">Find Client</a>
```

It then runs the required page. I need when the link is used for it to subtract one value from a SQL database I have.

The database has the following Rows

id  date  credit

```
$sql = "UPDATE items SET credit = credit - 1";
```

I have tried entering the above string into the code as such:

```
<a href="/lbs_map.php" target="_blank" class="$sql = "UPDATE items SET credit = credit - 1";">Find Client</a>
```

But can't seem to get it to work.

Please assist all I need is one credit to be deducted when the link is used. but the link must still preform the href as well

EDITED:

```
$sql = "insert into avis_lbs_log set lng = '".$long."', lat = '".$lat."', distance =   
'".$distance."', msisdn = '".$msisdn."', date_time = '".$today."'";
        $sql = "UPDATE avis_credit SET cred = cred - 1'";
```

Comment: You cant add PHP code to the class attribute and think it will be executed. Either try putting it in `lbs_map.php` as suggested or make an AJAX query.

Answer (score 3):

You have to fire this query in `lbs_map.php` to decrement the value

```
//lbs_map.php

<?php
//mysql connection
$sql = "UPDATE items SET credit = credit - 1";
//execute the sql query
//your rest of code
```

Comment: I have edited my question and added the string but then i get the following error.

at line 1mysql err no : 1064 $sql = "UPDATE avis_credit SET cred = cred - 1

Comment: @MaggieAckermann I have seen your edited question. This edit in unclear what you want to achieve. Also I think you didn't read my answer carefully. Read it properly.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is set up code that doesn't contain your statement. This is to prevent SQL injection. A better way of doing it is:

```
<a href="/lbs_map.php?do=update" target="_blank" class="update">Find Client</a>
```

Then in your `PHP`, you can check if `$_GET['do'] == 'update'` and perform the update.